# ephemeral disk noted listed on created ami Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, disk

Why ephemeral disk isn't listed on (fdisk -l) when i create a instance on amazon ec2 from my previously created (AMI)?

Comment: What instance size are you using?

Comment: I am having the same problem. I have launched 3 m1.medium instances from the EC2 web console, each with added ephemeral disks, but 1 instance does not have the ephemeral disk. I have terminated it and retried twice with no success

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to enable ephemeral storage on an instance.

1. Enable it at launch. Can be done in the console or command line tools.
2. Enable it with you register a snapshot as an AMI. By default it will not map ephemeral storage, this is something you have to explicitly enable.

Comment: when i launch a custom (AMI) the ephemeral disk is enabled in "Instance Store Volumes" Tab from "Request Instances Wizard", but when the instance start and i put (fdisk -l) in the console the ephemeral disk isn't listed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I confused the ephemeral disk instance ID with the disk quantity, and added ephemeral disk instance 1, rather than ephemeral disk instance 0. m1.medium instances only support 1 ephemeral disk, and it MUST be ephemeral disk instance 0.